# Grounding tv antenna in attic?

Tags: attic, grounding-and-bonding, tv-antenna

I know this question has been raised all over the internet, with a variety of responses, but here is my specific situation:

I purchased [this antenna](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082DN8L6T) and plan to mount it in my attic. I have an indoor pipe chase leading from my attic to the basement to feed the coax through, and I have conduit electric throughout the house, including the attic for a pull chain light.

First, because everything is enclosed within the house,  is there any reason to ground the antenna? Some threads on other forums mention you ground outdoor antennas because of static built up by wind/debris or protection from nearby lighting strikes and its magnetic field, where indoor antennas aren't subjected to this..

It seems the attic will negate most risks.  My attic, like most attics have soffit and roof vents. Does the moving air coming through these vents create any risk for the indoor antenna?

Lastly, if I do ground the antenna, would grounding it to the outside of the electrical conduit coming into the attic be where I should ground to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good choice on the antenna. Lots of high quality reception for free. In fact, OTA (over the air) TV signals are often of better digital quality than TV through cable distribution. Cable TV is compressed/decompressed one more stage, to reduce the digital data rate, squeeze more channels, and make more money.

And OTA latency is lower: you will cheer for a goal before your cable watching neighbours. Just the right excuse to buy an air horn!

And to your question:

> Is there any reason to ground the antenna?

For reception, Yagi antennas (the one you bought) are not grounded. This applies to the connecting cable (shield/core) and any of the active reception conductors: the rods/bars/arms/spokes of the antenna, not its mounting hardware.

Half dipole antennas (Ground plane monopole and Marconi antennas) are different, they have parts that must be electrically grounded. Theses are sprout antennas like the one on a car, and wire antennas for showrt-wave and HAM radio.

Exterior antennas must have their *mounting rod* grounded to provide electric discharge in the event of a lightning strike or static accumulation from other causes. The mounting rod is insulated from any of the active reception parts.

Air movement in your attic should not pose a problem.

You can use the "outside of the electrical conduit" provided the conduit has a continuous reliable electrical connection to earth-ground. You have to inspect it along its full length until you reach a working ground wire.

Grounding of mounting hardware is not required indoors. In any case, do not ground the electrical parts of the antenna.

Comment: Thank you for the great in depth response! The house was built a few years ago, and uses the conduit as its ground. But sounds like grounding won't be neccessary. That's one less thing to worry about.